# Constant pointers in different sections GCC

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, linker, constants

Is there a way to change the destination section of all constant pointers? For me, the option with '**attibute**' is not ok, because I need some solution that will not work without changes in the source code.

Here example:

```
char * myString = "Some string to print";
```

And as we know, `myString` is stored in the .data and points to the .rodata. The system will initialize it by copying it from the elf file during start of the application. But it is only raw data, it cannot be analyzed. The problem is, that when we don't have MMU, and we try to using -fPIC and .got, the pointer does not use the .got, so it is icorrect.

Comment: "I need some solution that will not work without changes in the source " Are you sure about that? At a guess you "I need some solution that will work without changes in the source ".

Comment: Maybe try writing a custom [linker script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html#Scripts)

Comment: A global pointer variable which is initialized like this needs a relocation in PIC code. I don't think there is a way around this, so you need to disable PIC code or write some tiny dynamic linker which performs the required relocations.

Comment: Actually I am using my own linker script in my own OS designed for embedded architectures (http://chocoos.org). I want to run ELF files in it. In general it works, but the problem is, that I dont have MMU, so I have to use -fPIC. The program is built and put into the SD card. The system analyzes the ELF file, reads program sections, and updates it. And this works despite of the situation, when the global pointer is initialized to the .rodata section. I know, that I can put the variable to the different section, and update the section, but I don't want to change the source code of the program

Comment: Otherwise everytime, when you want to built a program for the system, you will have to update all global variables. If you want to build gcc for example, it will take too much time

Answer (score 0):

To describe the situation in details, please take a look:

```
#include <oc_stdio.h>
#include <oc_stdtypes.h>

static char *       SomeString = "Hue hue, it is my string!\n";
static uint32_t     Variable   = 0xDEADBEEF;
static uint32_t *   Pointer    = NULL;
static uint32_t     Variable2  = 0xBEEFBABA;

//=========================================
/**
 * The main entry of the application
 *
 * @param Argc      Argument counter
 * @param Argv      Arguments array
 *
 * @return result
 */
//=========================================
int main( int Argc , char ** Argv )
{
    printf("Hello ChocoOS - userspace World!\n");
    printf("It is very nice to be here!\n");

    printf("Here is string from data section: '%s'\n", SomeString);
    printf("And here variable from data section: 0x%08X\n", Variable);

    Pointer = &Variable2;

    printf("Variable2 = 0x%08X\n", Variable2);
    printf("Pointer to Variable2 = 0x%08X\n", Pointer);
    printf("Value from pointer = 0x%08X\n", *Pointer);
    printf("String pointer = 0x%08X\n", SomeString);

    return 0;
}
```

Actual result is:
[Result of the program work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IEwB.png)

In the binary you can see, that the string is placed in the .rodata:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stlUD.png)

And as you can see in the output of the program, the pointer stores offset of the .rodata.

Answer (score 0):

And here is the proof, that the program correctly uses .got:
[ASM .got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEzrd.png)